# Texture animation and draw calls performance | OpenGLES 2.0 + Java

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm building a simple game on Android Studio by using Java and OpenGL ES 2.0.

If until now I was concerned more on the *creative side*, now I've come to a point where performance began to play an important role, indeed while testing it on my device (Samsung Galaxy S8) I started noticing some lag or scattering.

The game as I said is pretty simple, it's 2D and there are relatively few objects on screen (10/15). These objects move so there is a basic collision detection engine.

I created a class which helps me tracking performace and functions execution time (it creates a string where are indicated the name of the function and it's execution time, then I created a simple routine in Excel which sorts them all in a table. Any suggestion to track performance in a better way is welcome). From these tests I deduced that the slower parts of my game are **texture animations** and **draw calls**.

---

## Texture animation

With *texture animation* I mean the way I switch my textures in order to achieve a fluid animation. For example if I have a button on screen and I want the background of this button to be animated then I use this technique.

To achieve the animation I create one big texture and I put in it the *frames* of my animation. I put them in the lower part of the texture. I created a `Texture` class with a method `void animate (int numbOfFrames, int animDuration)` which I call every time I have to draw my animated object. This method switches texture coordinates based on the elapsed time.
What I think makes this method slow is the fact that it has to update texture componets in my object's VBO each time it is called.

I've also tried to put the frames of my animation in different texture (one frame = one texture), but my app ended up crashing after few seconds. Indeed I think that changing texture and uploading it almost every frame is very expensive.

I don't want to post the source code of my `Texture` class because I'd like to understand if the technique I use can be fine. If it is then I'll try to optimize it on my own. This is my first game so I want to learn by its development.

---

## Draw calls

The other slower part of my game are the draw calls.

I structured my app with different classes for different kind of objects. For example I created a class `Cars` for cars, `Planes` for planes and so on. Each object of each class stores its own values (for example its position, its texture, its speed, its coordinates, its model matrix, its shader program,  ...). Each object has a method to draw itself.

Then I created a class for each kind of object which take care of dynamically creating or removing them. For example I have a `Cars_Builder_`, a `Planes_Builder_`, ... Each *Builder* has an ArrayList which contains the objects to be drawn. When I call `xxxBuilder.draw()` it iterates into the ArrayList and calls the `draw()` method of each object.

[Online](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices) I've read that changing OpenGL states is expensive. By doing the way I'm doing I change them a lot of times. Indeed each draw call has to choose the right shader program, to bind data (`glVertexAttribPointer`), to call `glDrawArrays`, and another bunch of *state changing* stuff.

So I'm thinking of changing the implementation of `draw()` in each object kind's class (`Cars`, `Planes`, ...). I want to put the coordinates of each object of a each type I have to draw into a *big* array, then I call the real `draw()` method via `xxxBuilder`. This way I massively reduce the expensive calls (one for each type of object), but I have several doubts:

- I have to compute `MVPmatrix * vertex` on the CPU. Indeed each model has a different position.
- Even if objects of the same type are similiar, they aren't identical, for example the may have different textures. But how can I pass in to the shader different textureIDs if I have the same VBO, so I draw them with the same `glDrawArrays` call? If there is a way to fragment `glDrawArrays` call, then also my first doubt would be solved: indeed I would pass in different uniforms (so both textures and MVPmatrix) for each object.

---

Thanks for reading my questions and sorry if my english isn't very good or if I asked/said obvious things or if it is too broad.